# Change some text using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my code

```
    var payload ={"html":[
    {
        "caption":"Name",
        "name":"name",
        "type":"text",
        "required":true,
        "field_options":{"size":"small","description":""},
        "cid":"c11",
    },

      {
        "caption": "Please enter your clearance number",
        "type": "text",
        "required": true,
        "field_options": {},
        "cid": "c6"
      },
      {
        "caption": "Security personnel?",
        "type": "radio",
        "required": true,
        "field_options": { "include_other_option": false},
            "options": [{
                "caption": "Yes",
                "checked": false
            }, {
                "caption": "No",
                "checked": false
            }],


        "cid": "c10"
      },
      {
       "caption":"Country",
       "name":"country",
       "type":"select",
       "required":true,
       "options":[{ 
              "caption":"India", 
              "checked":false
            },
            {
              "caption":"US",
              "checked":true
            }
       ],
       "cid":"c23"
      }

    ]
```

Now i want to replace `caption` to `html` where type is select

I want to change this

```
 {
       "caption":"Country",
       "name":"country",
       "type":"select",
       "required":true,
       "options":[{ 
              "caption":"India", 
              "checked":false
            },
            {
              "caption":"US",
              "checked":true
            }
       ],
       "cid":"c23"
      }
```

to this

```
 {
       "caption":"Country",
       "name":"country",
       "type":"select",
       "required":true,
       "options":[{ 
              "html":"India", 
              "checked":false
            },
            {
              "html":"US",
              "checked":true
            }
       ],
       "cid":"c23"
      }
    ]
  };
```

How to replace caption to html using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
$.each(payload.html, function (i, item) {
    if (item.type == 'select') {
        $.each(item.options, function(o, option) {
            option.html = option.caption;
            delete option.caption;
        });
    };
});
```

Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e863yp5a/3/).

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this:

```
var payload ={"html":[
{
    "caption":"Name",
    "name":"name",
    "type":"text",
    "required":true,
    "field_options":{"size":"small","description":""},
    "cid":"c11",
}, {
    "caption": "Please enter your clearance number",
    "type": "text",
    "required": true,
    "field_options": {},
    "cid": "c6"
}, {
    "caption": "Security personnel?",
    "type": "radio",
    "required": true,
    "field_options": { "include_other_option": false},
    "options": [{
            "caption": "Yes",
            "checked": false
        }, {
            "caption": "No",
            "checked": false
        }],
    "cid": "c10"
}, {
   "caption":"Country",
   "name":"country",
   "type":"select",
   "required":true,
   "options":[{ 
          "caption":"India", 
          "checked":false
        }, {
          "caption":"US",
          "checked":true
        }
   ],
   "cid":"c23"
}

]};


payload.html[3].options[1].html = payload.html[3].options[1].caption;
delete payload.html[3].options[1].caption; 
console.log(payload.html[3].options[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this also using `map` and `hasOwnProperty` method.

Code snippets:

```
var data = payload.html;
var records = $.map(data, function (record) {
    if (record) {
        if (record.caption && record.type == "select" && record.options.length > 0) {
            var opt = record.options;
            $.map(opt, function (rec) {
                if (rec.hasOwnProperty("caption")) {
                    rec["html"] = rec["caption"];
                    delete rec["caption"];
                }
            });
        }
        return record;
    }
});
var updatedPayload = { html: records };
console.log(updatedPayload);
```

I hope you will like this !!!